# Adapter class to display songs in an Android ListView

Tags: java, android

I am learning Android with Udacity nanodegree (having no support) and this is my assignment of music app. It is just an interface and no music I have to add. So far so the app is running without any error but I wold like to get expert feedback to write code in better and optimized way to achieve the same result.

My entire project is in my [Bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/q2amarket/musicmasti/src/8175fe3e76d8613eb0fb3906eb75190ce99c29fb).

## SongAdapter.java

```
public class SongAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Song> {

    int     playingIndex = -1;
    boolean currentTrack = false;

    public SongAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull List<Song> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View             playlistItemView = convertView;
        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (playlistItemView == null) {
            playlistItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.playlist_item, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.albumCoverThumbnail = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_album_thumbnail);
            holder.songTitle = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_song_title);
            holder.songAlbumTitle = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_song_album_title);
            holder.songArtist = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_song_artist);
            holder.songPlayButton = playlistItemView.findViewById(R.id.playlist_play_button);

            playlistItemView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) playlistItemView.getTag();
        }

        final Song currentSong = getItem(position);

        // set data to the list item
        assert currentSong != null;
        holder.albumCoverThumbnail.setImageResource(currentSong.getSongAlbumCoverId());
        holder.songTitle.setText(currentSong.getSongTitle());
        holder.songAlbumTitle.setText(currentSong.getSongAlbumTitle());
        holder.songArtist.setText(currentSong.getSongSingers());

        // check the play status of the song item
        if (playingIndex == position) {
            holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
        } else {
            holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
        }

        // set song button action
        holder.songPlayButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);

                // pause current song on other click
                if (position == playingIndex) {
                    playingIndex = -1;
                } else {
                    playingIndex = position;
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                // pause play current track
                if (currentTrack) {
                    holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow_black_24dp);
                    currentTrack = !currentTrack;
                } else {
                    holder.songPlayButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_black_24dp);
                }
                currentTrack = !currentTrack;
            }
        });

        return playlistItemView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        ImageView   albumCoverThumbnail;
        TextView    songTitle;
        TextView    songAlbumTitle;
        TextView    songArtist;
        ImageButton songPlayButton;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`ListView` has been deprecated, a better practice would be to use `RecyclerView` and `RecyclerView.Adapter`, for more information: [Android RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)

Comment: ListView is not deprecated class or widget, you can still use it, a lot of app does. RecyclerView is usually recommended approach because better performance and clear API.